# top banner not getting rendered in full width for mobile view

Tags: html, css, razor

I made a top banner which is getting rendered in full width on web page, but when I try to see it in mobile view, the top banner gets shrieked by some percentage.

The html code written is like:

```
<style>

    .top-banner {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        background: #fee768;
        color: #555;
        font-size: 16px;
        padding: 10px 7px;
        font-weight: 600;
    }

    .top-banner:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        background: #ffc71f;
        color: #846934;
    }
</style>

<div>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/...." target="_blank" class="top-banner">
        Need help? Watch this Video
    </a>
</div>
```

This works fine on the web page, but when I view the same page on mobile the top banner doesn't gets rendered in full width.

I tried adding `position: fixed !important;` to the `.top-banner` css class, using this the width gets fixed but the bottom content of the page gets shifted upwards, i.e. the bottom content of the webpage gets over the top banner.

Kindly suggest me some way to solve this issue.

Comment: add a z-index to your banner if you want it above when position fixed. but it is not clear what the problem with the mobile width is - what is shrieked?  Looking at your css, it would look as if it is too wide - if that is the case, then just add `box-sizing: border-box` to your `.top-banner`

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t want other elements to appear above your top-banner, you can use

```
.top-banner {
  z-index:1000
}
```

The higher the value of the z-index, the more the element appears on top of other elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is because "padding: 10px 7px;" take 7px more space in the left and right of the element.

To fix:

replace

```
padding: 10px 7px;
```

with this

```
padding: 10px 0;
```

Comment: I think the reason is because "padding: 10px 7px;" take 7px more space in the left and right of the element

Answer (score 0):

did you tried removing padding and margin on mobile device ?
or
apply these style:

```
.parent-div{
display:flex;
height:320px;
width:100%;
}
.top-banner {
width:100%;
height:100%;
padding:0px;
margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add important on your code

```
.top-banner{
    width:100%!important;
}
```

it will force it to be 100% width

Comment: You should try not to use `!important` it will make your code less maintainable, the only time you should ever need to use it is if you use a third party plugin that adds an inline style you want to override